# Rastro/caminho/processo de um comandos php no computador

Tags: php

Estou interessado em saber o que é feito quando o PHP executa um `echo` ou `print` (por exemplo).

Tenho interesse em saber que rastro/caminho/processo ele faz no nível mais baixo da "linguagem de máquina". Como ele aloca isso na memória, em qual espaço ele alocou e etc.

Comment: Cara, na moral, leia o código do interpretador: https://github.com/php/php-src. Não acho que seja papel do SOpt te dar esse tipo de conhecimento mestigado.

Comment: É uma opção @EdgarMunizBerlinck. Vlw. Mas quando encontrar o dito cujo programa que fica escutando e cospe o resultado no terminal, irei postar pra a galera conhecer. Obrigado.

Comment: Veja se é isso que você está procurando: https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php Att.
Edgar Sandi

Comment: Edgar Muniz, estou pedindo ajuda para me explicarem algo? Estou com interesse de tools como o backtrace que o Edgar Sandi postou acima. Se fui infeliz no meu post, peço desculpas. Tentarei ser mais didático na próxima vez. Vlw man..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um post explicando exatamente o que eu procurava.
http://derickrethans.nl/more-source-analysis-with-vld.html
O programa VLD visualiza o código de operação (opcode) que um processador possui pra executar algumas tarefas.
Minha intenção ao utilizar a ferramenta, é entender a diferença de comportamento em baixo nivel, de funções que executam 'quase' a mesma coisa.
`echo` e `print` por exemplo.

Comment: Se é o que procurava, aceite-a como resposta.

Comment: Obrigado @Thomas